# System.Data.Linq.DataContext errorcodes or exceptions

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm debugging a database connection that I'm trying to make with System.Data.Linq.DataContext in C#.NET.

I basically create a context like this:

```
System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();
context = new DataContext("bogusconnectionstring", mappingSource);
```

I actually have that bogus connection string there at the moment.

The problem here is, is that I don't get any reason for the failed connection. I don't get an exception, no return or error codes, etc. currentContext.Connection.State reports being closed and context.DatabaseExists() says false, but I can't more information that that.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534562.aspx#Y91) doesn't give any information about it either, nor does Google.

How do I get a normal exception or error code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest, if only for debugging, handle the connection yourself for now, i.e.

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    var context = new DataContext(conn, mappingSource);
    // etc
}
```

this might at least get you started in terms of finding the problem at `Open()`...

But it sounds to me like maybe the DB (/catalog) doesn't exist, or the account doesn't have access to it.